# Fetch calls to RESTful API fail to authenticate on iOS after React Native 0.61 update

Tags: django, react-native, restful-authentication

I'm working on a React Native app which needs to make API calls to a RESTful API built on the Django REST framework. To authenticate, our API has a login endpoint which sends back a sessionid cookie in the header, which we then send back in future request headers to receive user-specific information.

On Android this works as expected, however on iOS when sending exactly the same request after successfully logging in the server throws an error due to the user being unauthenticated.

The only noticeable difference in these tests is that on iOS the server returns an empty sessionid after making the second call (sent with a valid sessionid):

```
"headers": Object {
    ...
    "Cookie": "sessionid=\"\"; ..."
}
```

We recently updated to Expo SDK 36, which includes an update to React Native 0.61. Prior to this update, both Android and iOS versions worked as expected, however I cannot be sure this was the direct cause as there was a ~2 week break over Christmas directly after updating before discovering the issue.

This snippet shows how we get the cookie when making a request (currently avoiding using extra libraries to simplify the process):

```
response = await fetch(requestConfig.url, requestConfig)
      .then(result => {
        let cookies = result.headers.get('set-cookie');
        if (cookies != null) {
          let sessionId = cookies.split(', ').find(element => element.match(/sessionid/))!.substring(10, 42);
          sessionId && (this.sessionId = sessionId);
        }
        return result;
      });
```

I have tried adding `credentials: 'include',` to the request, with no success.

The request itself looks like this on both platforms when making the authenticated request:

```
Object {
  "body": "<JSON_Request>",
  "headers": Object {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "sessionid=<sessionID>",
  },
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "<API_URL>",
}
```

I would very much appreciate some help if anybody has run into a similar issue with React Native 0.61, or can spot something I'm doing wrong!

Comment: I had almost this exact issue that started showing up after upgrading to Expo 37, and I see that you tried adding credentials: 'include' to the fetch call, but what worked for me was setting credentials: 'omit'. So my fetch ended up looking like fetch(`url`, {
      credentials: "omit",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Cookie: my_cookie_value,
      },

Comment: I ran into this issue on Expo SDK 36, iOS. The `credentials: "omit",` fix from @Jason worked for us as well. Thanks you're a lifesaver!